# Can't get Heroku to display my Spring Boot app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to deploy a spring boot app with MySQL database to Heroku. The app works on my local server port 8080, the build to Heroku succeeds, the deployment to Heroku succeeds, but when I open my app on Heroku it just shows application error.

I suspect it has something to do with the ${PORT} variable that Heroku assigns. I have researched how to change the port with spring boot and added it to a Procfile and application.properties file. I also tried system.properties and even a .env file, but none of it is working. I also commented out all the code relating to the database, because that wouldn't work on Heroku without also hosting the database. So I am really just trying to get the basic GET paths / and /Greeting to work.

heroku logs --tail:

```
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689215+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689215+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689216+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689216+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689217+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689217+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689217+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689218+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689218+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689218+00:00 app[web.1]: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689219+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689219+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689219+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689220+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689220+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689220+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689221+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689221+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689221+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689221+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689222+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689222+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689222+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689223+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 57 common frames omitted
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689224+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689224+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689224+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689225+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689225+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689225+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689226+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689227+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689227+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689227+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 60 common frames omitted
2021-12-09T12:07:53.689227+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T12:07:53.691483+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-09 12:07:53.691 ERROR 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.692011+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-09 12:07:53.691  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.702976+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-09 12:07:53.702  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.718223+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-09 12:07:53.717  INFO 4 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2021-12-09T12:07:53.718225+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T12:07:53.718226+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740870+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-09 12:07:53.740 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740872+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740886+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740887+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740888+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740888+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740889+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740889+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740890+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740890+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740890+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740891+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740891+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740891+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740892+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740892+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740892+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740893+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740893+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740893+00:00 app[web.1]: at hyperion.Doc2Blog.Doc2BlogApplication.main(Doc2BlogApplication.java:19) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740894+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740894+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740894+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740895+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740896+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740896+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740896+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740896+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740897+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740901+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740902+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740902+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740902+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740903+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740903+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740903+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740904+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740904+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740904+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740905+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740905+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740906+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740906+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740915+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740915+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740916+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740916+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740917+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 24 common frames omitted
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740917+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740917+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740918+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740918+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740918+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740919+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740921+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740922+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 41 common frames omitted
2021-12-09T12:07:53.740922+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T12:07:53.929245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-09T12:07:54.092144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My Procfile:

```
web java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/Doc2Blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
server.port=${PORT:8080}
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

My system.properties file:

```
java.runtime.version=17
```

My POML.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>hyperion</groupId>
    <artifactId>Doc2Blog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Doc2Blog</name>
    <description>Converts docs to blogposts</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are there no other details in your output from `heroku logs`? Please show us several lines of preceding context.

Comment: @Chris thanks, I have added the full logs now.

Answer (score 0):

When I deploy a Spring Boot app to Heroku, I set the port to 8080 in application.yml/application.properties and do not use a Procfile.